# Replace multiple non-digit char to 1 non-digit char

Tags: java, android, split, replaceall

I am working on app that read weight value from weighing indicator. The output from the indicator are contains with symbols, non digit char and also a number. I just want to extract the number. I have already turn non-digits and symbols into several pipes using regex `\D`. Then I wanted to turn this string

> ||||||||||1234||||||||||||||1234||||||||||||||1234||||||||||||||1234||||||||||||||1234||||

into

> |1234|1234|1234|1234

How could I possibly do that?

Comment: Couldn't you just regex again? Like this: `(\|[0-9]+\|)+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a regex replacement:

```java
String input = "||||||||||1234||||||||||||||1234||||||||||||||1234||||||||||||||1234||||||||||||||1234||||";
String output = input.replaceAll("\\|+", "|").replaceAll("\\|$", "");
System.out.println(output);  // |1234|1234|1234|1234|1234
```